# Sql Server Triggers. How does the trigger checks for Update Command?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a trigger for auditing purchase and sales table. The trigger is on INSERT and DELETE. To check if its "Insert", the condition is

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) > 0

BEGIN

END
```

How do I check if its an Update command inside the Trigger?

Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tables" that are in play in an update trigger are still called `inserted` and `deleted`, and the old values of the rows are in the `deleted` table, and the new values are in the `inserted` table.

You can use logic along these lines to detect whether you are in a insert, update or a delete:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
   ON  MyTable
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE -- you need to add the "update" here, 
                              -- in order to catch updates as well
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @insertedCount int
    Declare @deletedCount int
    select @insertedCount = COUNT(*) from inserted
    select @deletedCount = COUNT(*) from deleted
    if (@insertedCount != 0) -- we have some new values
      if (@deletedCount = 0)  -- do we have old values?
        print 'Inserting'
      else 
        print 'Updating'
    else
      print 'Deleting'

END
```

Answer (score 1):

An INSERT,DELETE trigger will not fire for updates.

.........................

Answer (score 1):

CREATE an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` all in one table

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0

BEGIN
   RETURN;
END;

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
          BEGIN
             -- for UPDATE
          END
      ELSE
          BEGIN
             -- for INSERT
          END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
      -- for DELETE
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've updated your trigger (as Mitch [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600996/15498)) to also apply to `UPDATE`s, you need to check for updates first:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from inserted) and EXISTS(select * from deleted)
BEGIN
   --Update
END
```

Note that I've switch to `EXISTS` rather than `COUNT(*)`. Exists more properly describes what we want to establish - that rows exist in the table. We don't care *how many* rows are in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank "SWeko" for the clue.

Now, this what I did and the Trigger worked.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Sample
  ON TableName
  FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) > 0
BEGIN 
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED) > 0
       BEGIN
          -- UPDATE (TABLE). 
       END
   ELSE
       BEGIN
          -- INSERT (TABLE).
       END
END
ELSE
   -- DELETE (TABLE).
   BEGIN 
   END
```